# barplot() different colors of grey for bars based on number of categories in a column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R. Within each dataframe there are 8 variables.

I want to make a barplot in which I want to assign different shades of grey to the bars based on the values in one specific variable.

This is how I made a barplot:

```
barplot(x$cov, names.arg = x$exon, 
    xlab = x$gene[1],
    ylab = "read depth" , 
    border = gray.colors(???))
```

The variable exon is composed of integers. E.g:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

So I want all the bars for which `$exon = 0` to be in one shade of grey
All the bars for which `$exon = 1` in another shade of grey and so on ...

Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, defined sample data frame containing `cov` and `exon` values.

```
x<-data.frame(cov=sample(1:20,20),exon=rep(0:4,each=4))
```

Used argument `col=` instead of `border=` as it is better visible in example.

Vector of gray colors is made as length of unique values of `exon` . Then `[]` is used to select color for each bar according to `exon` value.

```
barplot(x$cov, names.arg = x$exon, 
        ylab = "read depth" , 
        col = gray.colors(length(unique(x$exon)))[as.factor(x$exon)])
```

[image]