# Colouring barplot in R according to variable of data set

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

i am trying to colour the bars of a bar plot in R according to their year.
I did not succeed using read.table, that is why I tried to adapt this method:
[barplot() different colors of grey for bars based on number of categories in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382697/barplot-different-colors-of-grey-for-bars-based-on-number-of-categories-in-a-c)

I tried to create a mini data frame like this. And this works perfectly

`j=data.frame(plot=c("N10-11","N10-14","N13-11","N13-14"),dbh=c("60.6","68.5","55.6","61.5"),year=c("2011","2014","2011","2014"))`

trying to adapt this code

```
barplot(x$cov, names.arg = x$exon, 
    ylab = "read depth" , 
    col = gray.colors(length(unique(x$exon)))[as.factor(x$exon)])
```

to my dataset (even the easiest way...) results in this

`Error in barplot.default(j$dbh) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix`

I musst be missing a quite basic thing. 
Could you help me to solve my problem?
Furthermore I would like to use custom colours instead of letting R choose them automatically - how could I achieve this?

Greetings
Nico

Comment: You need a numerical value for height, and in your data dbh is a factor. But it would be easier to spot if your given data matched your example....

Comment: you mean the barplot function? I know this is just the function i tried to adapt - but as you see in the error message it does not even work typing barplot(j$dbh) - I do not understand the difference to the dataset posted ind the other topic...

Comment: Does it work if you do `barplot(as.numeric(j$dbh))`? And I meant that you gave us your data `j`, but code that runs on `x` with other variables. That means we have to tinker with code/data to reproduce your error. Could you post your own adaptation as well?

Comment: sorry for that! `barplot(j$dbh, names.arg = j$plot,
        ylab = "dbh" , 
        col = gray.colors(length(unique(j$year)))[as.factor(j$year)])` Adding `as.numeric` does the job!
`barplot(as.numeric(j$dbh), names.arg = j$plot,
        ylab = "dbh" , 
        col = gray.colors(length(unique(j$year)))[as.factor(j$year)])` perfect thank you! is there a simple possibility how to use two colours instead of doing this automatically?

Comment: What do you mean with 'simple possibility how to use two colours'?

Comment: sorry that was too early my code yiels barplots with tow colours thants cool but with the code I posted I get not the values written in my data set...
I mean that I need to choose the two colour manually... lets say "grey43" and "grey22"

Comment: You ask for two gray.colors, you get two gray.colors. I've added an answer with custom colors. For the future, please read up on how to ask a good question on SO.

Comment: That is allright! Too problems persist: 1. The barplots show not the right numbers (data set says "60.6","68.5","55.6","61.5") and barplot shows 2, 4,1 and 3
2. instead of having dark and light (which is already nice) I want to manually choose the tow colour R should use for the two years...

Comment: What do you mean with manually choosing color? You gave grey values, I put them in my answer. Surely you can figure out yourself how to change that?

Comment: And the other issue is solved by converting to character first (or inputting numbers). Should have spotted that; have fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#data in right format, height-variable needs to be numeric

j=data.frame(plot=c("N10-11","N10-14","N13-11","N13-14"),
             dbh=as.numeric(c("60.6","68.5","55.6","61.5")),
             year=c("2011","2014","2011","2014"))
#check this
> str(j)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ plot: Factor w/ 4 levels "N10-11","N10-14",..: 1 2 3 4
 $ dbh : num  60.6 68.5 55.6 61.5
 $ year: Factor w/ 2 levels "2011","2014": 1 2 1 2

mycols <- c("red","blue")

barplot(j$dbh, names.arg = j$plot, ylab = "dbh" , 
    col = mycols[j$year], ylim=c(0,70))
```

[image]

Comment: You can change the `mycols` vector to the colors you want.

Comment: Thank you Heroka! This script works with the restiction that the bars of the plot indicate 2, 4, 1 and 3 instead of the values written in the data set... can you reporduce this error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Did you by any change convert plot to numeric too? I have added my output to the answer.

Comment: Ok I missed to convert the height variable to numeric! Sorry for that - thank you for your superb and quick help!!!
sorry for the bad question! I will impove mysef.

Comment: No worries, it's what we're here for :) Everybody was a beginner once.